# WFS in QGIS : different boundingbox CRS than Feature CRS

Tags: qgis, wfs

I want to add a WFS 2.0 layer to my QGIS 3.16 and I have a bounding box issue: QGIS sends a bounding box in the *same* CRS than the layer CRS. But the server expects the bounding box to be in WGS84, whatever the Feature default SRS.

The `GetCapabilities` states:

```xml
<wfs:FeatureType>
<wfs:Name>LUMI_LUMITHD:Base_prise_BAL</wfs:Name>
<wfs:Title>Base_prise_BAL</wfs:Title>
<wfs:DefaultCRS>urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::102582</wfs:DefaultCRS>
<ows:WGS84BoundingBox>
<ows:LowerCorner>-29.22026123106372 39.04255677649548</ows:LowerCorner>
<ows:UpperCorner>70.12090695084257 84.78250333201653</ows:UpperCorner>
</ows:WGS84BoundingBox>
</wfs:FeatureType>
```

So it seems this `WGS84BoundingBox` is not implemented in QGIS WFS client. It seems [it already is implemented for WMS](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_ogc/ogc_client_support.html#id13)

Can anybody confirm this or point me to a solution ?
How can I make QGIS report a "standard" wgs84 bounding box ?

Note : I can work around the problem by removing the "Only request features overlapping the view extent" flag, but this leads to performance problems.
Note 2 : When I send a request through the browser with the correct WGS84 BBox, the server will answer with the features so it seams to be a problem on QGIS side.

Comment: I think this is a server issue rather than a QGis one

Comment: When I send a request through the browser with the correct WGS84 BBox, the server will answer with the features so it seams to be on QGIS side.

Comment: QGIS should request the data in 102582 with a corresponding BBOX, there should be no need to send a WGS84 bounding box

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The server is expecting the bounds to be in `urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::102582` (`wfs:DefaultCRS`) - the standard just requires that layers report a "standard" wgs84 bounding box too.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. My question is indeed : how can I make QGIS report a "standard" wgs84 bounding box ?

Comment: You say there are performance issues in a request? or that you want a report? Its very unclear what your problem is

Comment: thanks again, I have edited my question to make it hopefully clearer.

Answer (score 0):

Ian you where right ! The solution was to inform the ArcGIS Server that the request was indeed in EPSG::102582 by adding `?SRSNAME=EPSG:102582` to the WFS connection URL in QGIS.

After that, ArcGIS Server understands the data sent is not WGS84 but EPSG:102582 and filters accordingly.

Many thanks again Ian for the help !